# Push Notification API output coming as message_id

Tags: php, reactjs, api, rest, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making a push notification API with the testing message.
After running the API, getting success as output but instead of notification parameters only getting message_id.
{"multicast_id":1737172589085289593,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1608011476021426%dbb9b5fbf9fd7ecd"}]}

Here is the code of my API

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAPt6Fa78:AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXENtL-BRLMt5-sdMnJpMy' );

if(isset($_POST['fcm_token']) && !empty($_POST['fcm_token'])) {
    $registrationIds = array($_POST['fcm_token']);
}
else if(isset($_GET['fcm_token']) && !empty($_GET['fcm_token'])) {
    $registrationIds = array($_GET['fcm_token']);
}

$headers = array('Authorization: key='.API_ACCESS_KEY, 'Content-Type: application/json');
$msg = array(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);

$fields = array('registration_ids'=>$registrationIds, 'data'=> $msg);
 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);   
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On success, it will returns output containing message ID along with success or failure like below. It will not return notification parameters.

```
{
  "multicast_id":1737172589085289593,
  "success":1,
  "failure":0,
  "canonical_ids":0,
  "results":[{
     "message_id":"0:1608011476021426%dbb9b5fbf9fd7ecd"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue was related to the parameter, change 'data' to 'notification' and it worked perfectly.